# Adding a property of a dynamic type to a dynamic type

Tags: c#

I am trying to create dynamic types similar to this:

```
public class DataObjects
{
  public DataObjectsLesser1 SomeRandom0 { get; }
  public DataObjectsLesser2 SomeRandom1 { get; }
}

public class DataObjectsLesser1 
{
  public int Prop0 { get; }
}

public class DataObjectsLesser2
{
  public int Prop0 { get; }
}
```

The following complete code example is a cut down version of the real program, which uses a 3rd party api to create a tree structure where you can navigate the nested types.

In the real program I can easily create the top level type DataObjects and also empty versions of DataObjectsLesser1/2. The problem is when I want to create the properties of DataObjectsLesser1/2 - and IF the bug was to be replicated - then the value **"Prop" + num** in the most inner loop is ignored and the value **"SomeRandom" + i * 10** is used for the property name instead. I can't see any logical reason for this as the types are set as expected (int in the example).

I also do not know how to verify what is going on in the example. I get a dynamic type in the instance var with the properties I generated, but each property does not appear typed - just null properties with no way of telling what type has been generated. I need to navigate the object graph for testing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Threading;

namespace TyeTes
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, Type propertyType, string propertyName)
        {
            FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField(propertyName + "X", propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);
            PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
            MethodBuilder propertyGetter = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public |
                                                MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
            ILGenerator randomPropertyGetterIL = propertyGetter.GetILGenerator();
            randomPropertyGetterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            randomPropertyGetterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
            randomPropertyGetterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(propertyGetter);
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var assembly = new AssemblyName("FieldTypes");
            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(assembly, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assembly.Name);
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = DefineType(moduleBuilder, "DataObjects");

            foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 3))
            {
                TypeBuilder subTypeBuilder = DefineType(moduleBuilder, "DataObjectsLesser" + i);
                foreach (var num in Enumerable.Range(0, 2))
                {
                    CreateProperty(subTypeBuilder, typeof(int), "Prop" + num);
                }
                CreateProperty(typeBuilder, subTypeBuilder.CreateType(), "SomeRandom" + i * 10);
            }
            Type randomType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(randomType);
        }

        public static TypeBuilder DefineType(ModuleBuilder modBuilder, string typeName)
        {
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = modBuilder.DefineType(typeName,
                TypeAttributes.Public |
                TypeAttributes.Class |
                TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
                TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                TypeAttributes.AutoLayout,
                typeof(object));
            return typeBuilder;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "IF the bug was to be replicated"? I've tried your code and it seems to work properly so I wonder how we can help you then.

Comment: @konRadkokosa what about my last paragraph? Thanks

Comment: I suggest saving it to disk simply, as I've said in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your second question:

> I need to navigate the object graph for testing.

The easiest way that comes to my mind is to save dynamic assembly to disk and then look at it in [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) or other decompiler. To do that specify `AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave` option to `DefineDynamicAssembly` method and provide a filename in `DefineDynamicModule` method:

```
AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(assembly, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assembly.Name, 
                                                                 "temp.dll");
```

add then at the end:

```
assemblyBuilder.Save("temp.dll");
```

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work, the error message occurs on the first line: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Cannot have a persistable module in a transient assembly.

Comment: this is also need DefineDynamicAssembly(assembly, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave), please update your answer

Comment: @Jaycee, true, I've forgot to mention it. I've just updated my answer.